# After interphase,there are 2 chromatids in each chromosome so how many total chromosomes are there in a cell

Tags: mitosis

Before interphase each chromosome now has 1 chromatid. After interphase  each chromosome replicates and has 2 chromatids so how many chromosomes are there totally.